# Spring Boot (Event Handler) before every request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I dont want to use a advanced authentication like LDAP. I just want to build a very simple login session check before every request call.

A event handler that will check to see if the user has logged in and has a session and if not, it will redirect them before the system sends the request any controller.

Answer (score 2):

Use Spring [`HandlerInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html). Intercept every request and perform your checks. However, I would not advise it. This is error prone and insecure.

You can achieve what you need with [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) without LDAP.